# I want to strip / clean() a cell of everything except CHAR(015), but ASCII Control Characters can't SUBSTITUTE() out

Tags: excel, substitution

I'm looking to take a text string and remove everything except the carriage returns and normal text (so other control characters, spaces, bullet points and a few other bits of junk). However

```
 CLEAN(A1)
```

strips the carriage returns too.

I've tried a string of nested

```
 SUBSTITUTE(A1, CHAR(000), "")
 SUBSTITUTE(A1, CHAR(001), "")
```

etc

but it keeps defaulting to

```
 SUBSTITUTE(A1, CHAR(0), "")
 SUBSTITUTE(A1, CHAR(1), "")
```

and giving me an error. Any help?

Not very experienced in VBA, though I could gather some basics with a bit of googling.

Comment: Please note that `CHAR(001)` takes the integer value of the received parameter and returns the equivalent ASCII character. In this context, `CHAR(001)` is **EXACTLY** equal to `CHAR(1)`.

Comment: Further to @FDavidov, `char 015` (where 015 is an octal value) is decimal 13, so you want to use `Char(13)` instead.

Comment: @JackDeeth, I think (not 100% sure) that, by default, the `CHAR` function expects _decimal_ values and not _octal_.

Comment: Yes, that's right. OP wants to keep octal-015, so must use decimal-13.

Comment: Ah, helpful to know. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to remove:

- ASCII characters 0 through 9
- ASCII characters 11 and 12
- ASCII characters 14 through 32
- ASCII characters 127 through 255

then consider the following User Defined Function:

```
Public Function JunkKiller(S As String) As String
    Dim temp As String, a
    ary = Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255)
    temp = S

    For Each a In ary
        temp = Replace(temp, Chr(a), "")
    Next a
    JunkKiller = temp
End Function
```

[image]

This will retain both ASCII-10 and ASCII-13, if you also want to retain the space character, just remove the *32* from the `Array()` statement.

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

```
=JunkKiller(A1)
```

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Answer (score 2):

Carriage returns are `Char(13)`, which is 015 in octal. But you probably also want `Char(10)` which is line-return.

Nested substitutes do work, but awkwardly:

```
=...Substitute(Substitute(Substitute(A1,Char(1),""),Char(2),""),Char(3),"")...
```

You'll need to substitute `Char(1)` to `Char(31)` omitting `Char(10)` and `Char(13)`.

A saner method might be to make use of the `\n` newline code and the `\r` carriage return code:

1. Substitute `Char(10)` for `\n`
2. Substitute `Char(13)` for `\r`
3. `Clean` what's left
4. Substitute `\n` for `Char(10)`
5. Substitute `\r` for `Char(13)`

This would fail if your input contains `\n` or `\r`, obviously.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(CLEAN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B1,CHAR(13),"\r"),CHAR(10),"\n")),"\r",CHAR(13)),"\n",CHAR(10))
```

There, only 4 `Substitutes` instead of 29!

Comment: Thank you, I'll give this a test.